# Appending to list in cells in newer versions of pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This code works in `pandas` version 0.23.4 but throws an error in version 0.25.1 and newer.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b': [[0,1], [5], [10]]})
df

    a   b
0   1   [0, 1]
1   2   [5]
2   3   [10]

# both lines below throw an error in newer versions
df['b'] += [42]
df.loc[df['a']==3, 'b'] += [73]
df

# desired output that works in 0.23.4
    a   b
0   1   [0, 1, 42]
1   2   [5, 42]
2   3   [10, 42, 73]
```

How does append to list in cells work in later versions on pandas ?

Comment: This is a known issue see : https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/28261

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
df['b'].apply(lambda x: x.append(42))
df.loc[df['a']==3, 'b'].apply(lambda x: x.append(73))
```

(tested on pandas version 1.0.5)

Comment: I was convinced `lambda` would be slower, but some quick testing shows it's actually faster. Great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways:

**Method 1**

```
df['b'] = pd.concat([df['b'], pd.Series(42)], axis=1)['b']
df.loc[df['a']==3, 'b'] = df.loc[df['a']==3, 'b'].to_numpy().tolist()[0] + [73]
```

---

**Method 2**

```
from itertools import zip_longest

ls = list(zip_longest(df['b'], [42]))

df['b'] = [x[0] for x in ls]

print(df)

   a           b
0  1  [0, 1, 42]
1  2     [5, 42]
2  3    [10, 42]
```